# Extrude and scale problem

Tags: extrude

So I am following along on a video and I can't scale when extruding like on the video. When I do it, my object duplicates into a copy instead of expanding as I want it to.

I am in edit mode.
I mouse over the object and press L
median point is selected
I press E then the axis.

But my result is wrong as you can see in the picture. The left is mine and the righ is the result I "should" get

There is a step i am missing.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Select the whole object in edit mode (while in face select mode), right click and select "Extrude faces along normals".

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried that but it does not look the same ( or i am did something wrong in a prior step. 

It just bloats everything outward.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe try the "usual" (mesh problem) things first. Select all in edit mode then press M (merge) and select "By distance" - this will make sure you don't have any stray verts/edges. Then while still all selected, press Shift+N (Recalculate Normals Outside). Then finally, select the object in object mode and press Ctrl+A and select "Scale" (removes possibility of non-uniform scale). Then try the extrusion again

Comment: Ok so manager to get the desired shape ( but I am not sure how I did it and I can't reproduce it ). I did all you said. 

So here is the funny thing 

In edit mode. 
I select all ( press L ) 
If I press E the move thing happens. 
If I press enter I get extrude and move region. The move seems to be the wrong part. 

hmmmm

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d414e4acdaf34598a077180b42263d99 
@moonboots

Comment: it works fine for me, I've deleted everything except one U, then press E (you can also try Alt E > Extrude Faces along Normal), then Enter, then S Shift Z so that it scales on X and Y only

Comment: Resolve thanks moon